# Automatically Update a Pivot Table Based Based on Cell Reference

Tags: excel, vba

I have a pivot table with the following columns:
`item_number`, `job_number`, `description` and `qty`.

I would like to have `VBA` code take the input of a cell, `A5`, to automatically sort through the `job_number` column of my pivot table and find the entries that have the `job_number` found within `A5`.

The data set is very large, so it is not a wise idea to sort through using `PivotItems`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a file that does exactly that. I have a cell which isn't part of the pivot table but acts like a filter field for the pivot table.

I put a script into the `Worksheet_Change` event to watch that cell for changes and a sub which swaps out the filter on the pivot table to match the cell value.

The `Worksheet_Change` event is basically like

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A5")) Is Nothing Then Call FilterChanger
End Sub
```

And the `FilterChanger` sub is basically like

```vb
Private Sub FilterChanger()
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim FilterText as String
    FilterText = Me.Range("A5")

    With Me.PivotTables("MyPivotTable")
        .ManualUpdate = True
        .PivotFields(3).ClearAllFilters
        .PivotFields(3).PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlCaptionContains, Value1:="zzzzzzzzzzzz" 
        'Filter out all results to prevent table updating when clearing filters

        .PivotFields(5).ClearAllFilters 
        'now that there is another filter, there isnt any lag while the table tries to load all the unfiltered data

        .PivotFields(5).PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlCaptionEquals, Value1:=FilterText, Value2:=FilterText
        .PivotFields(5).ShowDetail = True
        .PivotFields(3).ClearAllFilters
        .ManualUpdate = False
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

In this code `PivotFields(3)` is any pivot row field that is in the table other than the one you intend to filter. and `PivotFields(5)` is the field that I am targetting with my filter. You can put column names instead of a number when referring to your fields, but I just prefer numbers.

In my file, the source data for the pivot table is 20k rows and growing, so I found that whenever I did `.ClearAllFilters` the workbook would pause for ~10 seconds while the pivot table attempted to load all 20k rows. To fix that issue, I put in a temporary filter in another field which will prevent any rows from loading while I swap out the filter in the intended field. I chose `zzzzzzzzzzzz` in `PivotField(3)` because it will always return 0 rows.

Comment: When I run this code, I come across an error: "Application-defined or object-defined error" on the following line: .PivotFields(5).ShowDetail=true. This is after I change my fields to be the appropriate ones.

Comment: Strange, on my code, it runs the line with no issues but if I set it as a watched value in the debugger, the value during execution is an error. I think even if you remove the line, the rest of the code should still do what you want it to do.

Comment: It seems like the code does nothing now... all the data points are still being displayed??

Comment: Edit your post and add in the modified code in full, I'll take a look and see if I can spot the issue.

Comment: I recopied and pasted the code again and just took out that one line and it worked... so thank you!

Comment: @logan You're welcome! I'm glad to hear it worked. If my answer solved your problem, I would appreciate if you gave my answer the check mark.

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Sub Macro1()
    ' in A1 there is the value for sorting
    ' if you want to show the whole table again run only the "select all" part (line 2):

    ' Field value == Column (right now column 2); Criterial == Filter Value (value of cell A1) ; change Table name to yours
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Range("A1").Value
    

    ' "Select All -- to show whole table again de-comment following line
    'ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=2
    
End Sub
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.